# WPF Square auto-size to parent container

Tags: wpf, user-interface, autolayout, resize, autoresize

I have a `UniformGrid` object in my WPF project that has 2 rows and 3 cols and its width and height are set to auto (with both alignments set to Stretch).

This grid will hold 6 **squares** that I want to fill as much of their cell as possible and be centered horizontally and vertically.

What do I need to be added to allow for the squares to increase/decrease their length/width based on the dynamic size of the parent?  I.E., when the window is resized.

Here is my xaml so far:

```
    <UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="3">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="100" Stroke="Black" Width="100"/>
    </UniformGrid>
```

Edit:

And the `Rectangle` objects need to remain square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >
  <Grid>
<UniformGrid Rows="2" Columns="3">
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"><Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" /></Viewbox>
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"><Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" /></Viewbox>
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"><Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" /></Viewbox>
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"><Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" /></Viewbox>
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"><Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" /></Viewbox>
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform"><Rectangle Height="100" Width="100" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Stroke="Black" /></Viewbox>
    </UniformGrid>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Note that this will SCALE the rectangle, not size it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
<UniformGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
        <Setter Property="Width"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},Path=ActualHeight}" />
    </Style>
</UniformGrid.Resources>
```

Or you could bind the Height to the ActualWidth.

Unfortunately this will not keep them stretched to the maximum.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove the `height` and `width` properties it will do just that.