# Creating a square UserControl

Tags: wpf, user-controls, grid, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am designing a user control that needs to be square, and to fill as much room as it is given (to give some context, it is a checkboard).

My user control looks like:

```xml
<Grid>
    <!-- My 8 lines / colums, etc. , sized with "1*" to have equal lines -->
</Grid>
```

Now I would simply like to say "This grid has to be square no matter what room it has to expand".

**Tried Solutions in vain:**

1. I can't use a `UniformGrid` because I actually have the names of the lines & columns in addition, so I have a leading header row and column with different sizes.
2. If I use a `Viewbox` with `Uniform` it messes all up.
3. I tried using the classic

   ```xml
   <Grid Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Width}"> ... </Grid>
   ```

but it only works if I manually set the `Width` property. Otherwise, this constraint is ignored.

**Conclusion**

I'm out of idea, and I would really like to avoid setting `Width` / `Height` manually as this control may be used in many various places (`ListItem` templates, games, etc...).

---

**Solution from suggestion:**

A solution is available with some code-behind. I did not find a XAML only solution.

Grid is now:

```xml
<Grid SizeChanged="Board_FullControlSizeChanged">...</Grid>
```

And the event handler is:

```cs
private void Board_FullControlSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs args)
{
    double size = Math.min (args.NewSize.Height, args.NewSize.Width);
    ((Grid)sender).Width = size;
    ((Grid)sender).Height = size;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your edit for "Solution from suggestion" even works when you apply the SizeChanged Handler directly to the Grid? When I tested this, The Grid stops receiving any Size changed calls after the initial call and you setting a width & height on it through code. Thus henceforth any re-size just positions the grid center and no more actual size change. The logic is much cleaner using a Math.Min however I had to apply the SizeChanged handler to the parent 'UserControl' and not on the Grid itself. I updated my post with the new logic as well.

Comment: Ah good point, didn't notice that side-effect since my Grid is not resized another time in my app. Do you know where this behavior comes from? I'll try that tonight on my code and will update my post accordingly. Thanks for your follow-up.

Comment: No problem. Not too sure where it's coming from, wild guess would be SizeChanged handler is ignored in the event chain before it's called when concerned element has fixed dimensions and thus we only see the initial call that which hence disables future calls.

Comment: Correct. When you set a fixed sized, it will no longer change size automatically, so `SizeChanged` will never be called again. What you need to do is name your grid something (such as `Board`), then hook up your `SizeChanged` event to the control itself. When the control changes size, then you can use `Board.Width = size` in your code above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I initially tried modifying your binding to `ActualWidth` and it still did not work when the `Grid` was the top level element and in some cases it ended up expanding the control further than the available size. Hence tried some other ways of getting the required output.

Got 2 ways of maybe addressing this:

Since this is a view related issue (not breaking MVVM, keeping a square formation, if your ok with having a bit of code-behind, you could do something like)

```
private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
  double minNewSizeOfParentUserControl = Math.Min(e.NewSize.Height, e.NewSize.Width);
  mainGrid.Width = minNewSizeOfParentUserControl;
  mainGrid.Height = minNewSizeOfParentUserControl;
}
```

and in your xaml you would name your main top level grid "mainGrid" and attach the `UserControl` size changed event handler to the above function not the `Grid` itself.

However if you totally hate code-behind for whatever reason, you can be a bit more fancy and create a behavior such as

```
public class GridSquareSizeBehavior : Behavior<Grid> {
  private UserControl _parent;

  protected override void OnAttached() {
    DependencyObject ucParent = AssociatedObject.Parent;
    while (!(ucParent is UserControl)) {
      ucParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(ucParent);
    }
    _parent = ucParent as UserControl;
    _parent.SizeChanged += SizeChangedHandler;
    base.OnAttached();
  }

  protected override void OnDetaching() {
    _parent.SizeChanged -= SizeChangedHandler;
    base.OnDetaching();
  }

  private void SizeChangedHandler(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    double minNewSizeOfParentUserControl = Math.Min(e.NewSize.Height, e.NewSize.Width);
    AssociatedObject.Width = minNewSizeOfParentUserControl;
    AssociatedObject.Height = minNewSizeOfParentUserControl;
  }
}
```

For the behavior your xaml would then look like:

```
  <Grid>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <local:GridSquareSizeBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </Grid>
```

Did test these two methods with Snoop and the square size was maintained while expanding/shrinking. Do note both methods in the crux use the same logic(just a quick mock-up) and you might be able to squeeze some better performance if you update the logic to only update height when width is changed and vice versa instead of both and canceling a resize all together if not desired

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I never used `Behaviors` so I'll stick to the code-behind solution you propose, it looks easy enough and really it's a case where code-behind looks totally ok to me.

Comment: Your welcome :) yeh Behaviors has its advantages in certain places where you might want to say reuse this in other UserControls for example. You thus have lesser code duplication and can get away with not having your grid named in the xaml. Just boils down to specific use cases. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your grid in a ViewBox: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx

Here's a code sample I came up with:

The usercontrol:

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackOverflow.CheckBoard"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Viewbox>
        <Grid Background="Red" Height="200" Width="200">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Content="testing" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <Button Content="testing" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button Content="testing" Grid.Row="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</UserControl>
```

And the main window:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:AllNoneCheckboxConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <local:CheckBoard MaxWidth="80"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

What this Viewbox will do is scale the control to the space it's given. Since the grid inside the viewbox is square, the grid will ALWAYS stay square. Try playing around with the MaxWidth property I used in the MainWindow.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But as I mentioned in the original post, I don't want to use a ViewBox because it messes all up. I have lots of controls inside the Grid, and if I use a `Viewbox` the grid is sure square, but controls inside it also get scaled. Plus the behavior with rows and stuff gets all messed up somehow when using a `Viewbox`. I didn't investigate more, it is so messed up that I wanted a different solution altogether. Thanks though.

Comment: Crap sorry. I must have missed that :(

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the `Height` property to `ActualWidth` instead of `Width`:

```
<Grid Height="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    ...
</Grid>
```

However, a better solution would be to use a Viewbox. The trick to avoid that it "messes all up" is to make its Child square by defining (sensible) equal values for Width and Height:

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid Width="500" Height="500">
        ...              
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Tried both of these with snoop verifying dimensions. First one gives you the size requirement however it ends up stretching one dimension if needed off the bounds of the viewport to maintain the square than restrict the other dimension to not expand. Second method looks like it works Visually, however as stated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682345/wpf-square-auto-size-to-parent-container ViewBox Scales the child. Resize then does not change the size of the grid but just ends up scaling the child to the new size.

Comment: The first solution obviously makes part of the control invisible when the available area's width is larger than its height. I'm just showing how to correctly do the binding (ActualWidth instead of Width). Anyway, the Viewbox solution is the easiest way to get a square control. Of course the Grid is never resized, as Width and Height are set to fixed values. I guess resizing is simply not needed here.

Comment: Yeah, tried the one with `ActualWidth` too, didn't mention it in my original post. Didn't work either. I would like to avoid `Viewbox` because it scales everything inside, it is not nice. For example, if I want a column of my `Grid` to be exactly `20` wide no matter what, I can't do it because the `Viewbox` will rescale everything.

Answer (score 0):

Register wherever it suits you (usually in constructor or OnAttached()):

```cs
SizeChanged += Square;
```

and handle size with this:

```cs
private void Square(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.HeightChanged) Width = e.NewSize.Height;
    else if (e.WidthChanged) Height = e.NewSize.Width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by setting the margin of the contained control from inside the parent control's size changed event.
In my case I have a 'sudoku grid' user control called SudokuBoard inside a standard Grid control called MainGrid (which fills the main window) and it only requires the following code;

```
    private void MainGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double verticalMargin = Math.Max((e.NewSize.Height - e.NewSize.Width)*0.5, 0.0);
        double horizontalMargin = Math.Max((e.NewSize.Width - e.NewSize.Height)*0.5, 0.0);
        SudokuBoard.Margin = new Thickness(horizontalMargin, verticalMargin, horizontalMargin, verticalMargin); 
    }
```